# linear transport equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the linear transport equation:
$$u_t+cu_x=0$$

Using the centered scheme: $$\dfrac{u_{i}^{n+1}-u_{i}^{n}}{\triangle t}+c\dfrac{u_{i+1}^{n}-u_{i-1}^{n}}{2\triangle x}=0$$

I would like to evaluate the time order and space order of this scheme.

The truncation error has the form $$\dfrac{u_{i}^{n+1}-u_{i}^{n}}{\triangle t}+c\dfrac{u_{i+1}^{n}-u_{i-1}^{n}}{2\triangle x}$$

Using Taylor expansion

$$\dfrac{\left[u_{i}^{n}+\triangle tu_{t}+O\left(\triangle t^{2}\right)\right]-u_{i}^{n}}{\triangle t}+c\dfrac{\left[u_{i}^{n}+\triangle xu_{x}+O\left(\triangle x^{2}\right)\right]-\left[u_{i}^{n}-\triangle xu_{x}+O\left(\triangle x^{2}\right)\right]}{2\triangle x}$$

Simplifying gives

$$u_{t}+O\left(\triangle t\right)+cu_{x}+O\left(\triangle x\right)$$

Since $u_{t}+cu_{x}=0$
 , we get first order in time and space.

But I know that this scheme has second order in space, first order in time.

What mistakes I have? How should I fix them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Keep the second order term of taylor series in $x$. Then it will work.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain it more precisely?

Comment: You expanded $u_{i+1} = u_i + \Delta x u_i + O(\Delta x^2)$. Instead, do the expansion keeping second order terms as well.

Comment: You mean $u_{i+1}=u_i+\triangle x u_x+\triangle x^2 u_{xx}+O(x^3)$?

Comment: Not quite, your second order term is incorrect, it should be $\frac{1}{2} \Delta x^2 u_{xx}$.

Comment: Those terms will be cancel out by the $-$ between $u_{i+1}$ and $u_{i-1}$

Comment: OK I've got that. Thank you very much.